# Magento - failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: magento

Tried to update my magento website and now i have this error.
I think there will be more error's after this one.

```
Warning: include(Inchoo/Customergroup/Model/Observer.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory  in /home/<namefolder>/<namefolder>/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I Can't find a solution to fix this. Where do i start?

Comment: When you say "update" which versions are you talking about?

Comment: 1.8 > 1.9.1 I updated my modules and then this happend.

Comment: Check that `/home/<namefolder>/<namefolder>/lib/Varien/Autoload.php` file exists or not. If not exists then copy that file from the downloaded copy of the magento 1.9.1.1

Comment: I will try that, the strange thing is that the url is  lib/Varien/Autoload.php and not /home/<namefolder>/<namefolder>/lib/Varien/Autoload.php

Comment: Where can i remove /home/<namefolder>/<namefolder>/? I think this will fix the error.

Comment: Have you flushed Magento's cache after updating your module ?